# Create video from image.ppm c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I don't how to create a video with image sequences.
My image are save in file (the extension is **.ppm)**, the type of the file is so **FILE*** not a Mat like I can found in others topics who someone want to create a video too but he uses Mat type.
For example, i save 5 images in 5 files (one image per file so) and i want to create a video with the order of the image (image0 to image4) and one sec in the video match with one image.
Here my code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void colortemp(float temp, FILE* tempfile)
{
    float temp_min = -138.0;
    //float temp_max = -37.0;
    float color_min = 240.0;
    //float color_max = 0;
    
    if(temp < 135.0f)
    {
        temp = 135.0f;
    }
    
    if(temp > 310.0f)
    {
        temp = 310.0f;
    }
    float a = ( 0.0f - 240.0f) / ( 310.0f - 135.0f);
    float b = 240.0f - (a * 135.0f);
    float h = (temp * a ) + b;
    
    float S = 1.0f, V = 1.0f; //HSV
    float P, Q, T, fract;
    
    unsigned char pix[3];

        (h == 360.0f)?(h = 0.0f):(h /= 60.0f);
        fract = h - floor(h);

    P = (V*(1. - S))*255;
    Q = (V*(1. - S*fract))*255;
    T = (V*(1. - S*(1. - fract)))*255;
    
    V*=255;
    S*=255;

    if (0. <= h && h < 1.)
    {
            pix[0] = (int)V;
            pix[1] = (int)T;
            pix[2] = (int)P;
    }

    else if (1. <= h && h < 2.)
    {
        pix[0] = (int)Q;
            pix[1] = (int)V;
            pix[2] = (int)P;
    }

    else if (2. <= h && h < 3.)
    {
        pix[0] = (int)P;
            pix[1] = (int)V;
            pix[2] = (int)T;
    }
    
    else if (3. <= h && h < 4.)
    {
        pix[0] = (int)P;
            pix[1] = (int)Q;
            pix[2] = (int)V;
    }
    
    else if (4. <= h && h < 5.)
    {
        pix[0] = (int)T;
            pix[1] = (int)P;
            pix[2] = (int)V;
    }
    
    else if (5. <= h && h < 6.)
    {
        pix[0] = (int)V;
            pix[1] = (int)P;
            pix[2] = (int)Q;
    }
    
    else
    {
        pix[0] = 0;
            pix[1] = 0;
            pix[2] = 0;
    }
    
    fwrite(pix,1,3,tempfile);
}

int main()
{

// TRANSFORM 3D MATRIX INTO 2D MATRIX
vector<vector<vector<float>>>vec3d(10,vector<vector<float>>(10,vector<float>(10)));
vector<vector<float>>vec2d(10,vector<float>(10));

FILE *imageFile;
int height=1000,width=1000;
//int height=10,width=10;

vector<Mat> images;
//srand((unsigned int) time(0));
int cpt = 0;
for(int temps = 0; temps < 5; temps ++)
{
    srand(temps);
    //Modify the 3d matrix -> add cpt
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
                vec3d[x][y][z] = rand()%300;
                //vec3d[x][y][z] = x + cpt;
    
    cpt++;

    //Fix z to get a same slice 
    int z = 8;
    //3D matrix to 2D matrix
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            vec2d[x][y] = vec3d[x][y][z];
            
            
    //name of the image
    char filename[50]="";
    const char* filename_tmp = "image";
    string s = to_string(temps);
    char const *numberFile = s.c_str();//use char const* as target type
    const char* extension = ".ppm";
    
    strcat(filename,filename_tmp);
    strcat(filename,numberFile);
    strcat(filename,extension);
    
    cout << filename << " = name_file" << endl;

    //open the file
    imageFile=fopen(filename,"wb");
    if(imageFile==NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR: Cannot open output file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    fprintf(imageFile,"P6\n");               // P6 filetype
    fprintf(imageFile,"%d %d\n",width,height);   // dimensions
    fprintf(imageFile,"255\n");              // Max pixel
    
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
                for(int k = 0; k <100 ; k++)
                    colortemp(vec2d[x][y],imageFile);
                
    
    fclose(imageFile);
} 

return 0;
}
```

I read this topic : [create a video from image sequence in open cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704236/create-a-video-from-image-sequence-in-open-cv) 
But the answer use Mat type (I don't how if it's possible to convert FILE* -> Mat, I try to code this but it doesn't work) and some of the variable are unknown, not defined.
Furthermore, I read the link of the answer of the topic and the tutorial use arguments but the program need to create the video when I execute **without arguments**.

Thanks for help

EDIT: I try that but it doesn't work.

at the end of the loop for the time of my program i add :    `Mat image = imread(filename,cv::IMREAD_COLOR);` and `Mat image = imread(filename,cv::IMREAD_COLOR);` and `images.push_back(image);`
And i create the video :

```
VideoWriter outputVideo("outcpp.avi",cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'),10,Size(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)); 

    for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++){
        outputVideo.write(images[i]);
    }
    outputVideo.release();
    cout << "Finished writing" << endl;
```

The code compile but I can't open the video...

Comment: If your problem is that you don't know how to load an image into a `cv::Mat`... That's actually very easy: `using namespace cv; std::string name = "file.ppm"; Mat image = imread(name.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` (copied from [OpenCV Tutorials - Load and Display an Image](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html)). It appears a bit shorter than your code and probably supports various image file formats. (I must admit that I don't have experience with OpenCV but a bit with [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+mat+load+image+c%2B%2B).)

Comment: _but the program need to create the video when I execute **without arguments**._ You are free to implement the creation of file name in any way. I would suggest something with a loop and `std::to_string()`. ;-) Btw. clicking further in the above link I noticed that `using namespace cv; std::string name = "file.ppm"; Mat image = imread(name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` should do as well. (The first parameter of `imread()` in C++ is actually of type `std::string` - how convenient.)

Comment: @Scheff If I do ```Mat image = imread(name.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);``` ,  the object containt the image i think ? If yes, I need to save my variable image in a array or vector. And this array is going to be use to create the video but like the link if I do : vector<Mat> mat_im = image. I have a segfault. However I put an object Mat, it is strange no ?

Comment: Do you know how `std::vector` works? To add elements to a `std::vector` you have to use [std::vector::push_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [std::vector::emplace_back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) or you have to ensure that the `std::vector` provides a sufficient number of elements from beginning.

Comment: Yep my bad ! Thanks I can fill the vector then ! I was so dumb... anyway I'm going to wait others response to show me how to create a video, what I need etc.
Thanks again for your answer !

Comment: Do you have some reason to write a whole program to do this? It's a simple one-liner with `ffmpeg` and will run miles faster and on any platform with far more flexibility.

Comment: @Newbi In your last edit, can you be sure,```images[i]``` instances are okey? Can you try to ```imshow``` them before writing? If they all okey, then while trying to open the video, what type of error your OS is giving?

Comment: With a big possibility, the elements of ```images vector``` is empty.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I can show all of the images so all of them are ok. If I try to open with the vlc  : ``` Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
[00007f8cfc0010f0] avi demux error: no key frame set for track 0
[00007f8cfcc100c0] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[00007f8d10009a80] avi demux error: no key frame set for track 0
[00007f8d10001600] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread ```

Comment: @MarkSetchell my supervisor prefers that I code myself a feature to create a video than using an external program (even with the help of a fork)

Answer (score 0):

[Writing video with openCV - no key frame set for track 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598149/writing-video-with-opencv-no-key-frame-set-for-track-0/47751188)

This link can help to understand how to initialize an object VideoWriter.
I use the constant for the width and height but I should put the size of my matrix , here the code :

```
sizzz = Size(image.cols, image.rows);
VideoWriter outputVideo("outcpp.avi",cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'),2,sizzz); 

if(outputVideo.isOpened() == false)
{
    cout << "error" << endl;
    return -1;
}
for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++)
{
    outputVideo.write(images[i]);
        if (images[i].empty())
        {
            cout << "problem" << endl;
            break;
        }

}

outputVideo.release();
```